# How to solve classification problem where Dataset amount is low and features between two classes are similar/confusable

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am currently training a cnn to classify ICs into the classes "scratch" and "no scratch" (binary classification). I am fairly new to deep learning and when I trained my cnn a little bit I got very good accuracies (Good validation accuracy as well). But I quickly learned that my models where not as good as I thought, because when using them on a dataset to test it, it got quite a lot of false classification (false positives and false negatives). In my opinion there are 2 problems:

1. There is too little training data (about 1000 each class)
2. The ICs have markings (text) on it, which changes with every batch, so my training data has images of ICs with varying markings on it. And since some batches have more scratched ICs and other have less or none, the amount of IC images with different markings is unbalanced

here are two example images of 2 ICs from training set of the class "scratch":

[image]

[image]

As you see the text varies very strong. Every line has different characters and the amount of characters also varies.
I ask myself how the cnn should be able to differentiate between a scratch and an character?
Nevertheless I am trying to train my cnn and this is for example one model I currently trained (the other models look quite similar):

[image]

There are some points while training where the validation accuracy gets up and then down again. What could that mean? I think it is something like that there is a feature in the val data set that is not covered in my training set. Could this be the cause?

As you see Data Augmentation is no option (Or so I think) because of the text. One thing that came into my mind is to seperate the marking and the IC (cut out text region) with preprocessing (Don't know how I could do it properly and fast) and then classfy them seperately, but I don't know if this would be the right approach.

I first used VGG16, ResNet and InceptionV3 (with transfer learning). Now I tried to train my custom cnn (inspired by VGG but with 10 layers similar to this: https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/1558925019897396)

Do you guys know how I should approach this problem or do you have any tips?

Comment: on the second example image that you posted, do you consider the scratched area as the white dot next to the text, or the one on top of the text? I'm trying to think of ways in which you can get the characters in the image out of the learning process... maybe, like you said, cutting the non-text area using PIL,or somehow filling the text space with background?

Comment: @Orozco the three dots near to the big "e" are part of the logo of the manufacturer, so they are no scratches. As you said every white "spot" on the surface that is no character (or symbol) is considered a scratch.
The approach with cutting out the text (or non-text) area seems to be the most intuitive one, but as I mentioned, I am not that familiar with opencv. Actually the images I posted here are already preprocessed, where I cut out the IC from the unnecessary background. But how to cut out the text I don't have a clue ^^